# How to make text NOT flow around image, and to make it fall under image responsively

Tags: css, text

I want to have an image floated left, with text to the right that doesn't flow around it, and that falls underneath it when the browser is minimised. Like this:

[image]

This is the css I've got at the moment:

```
.item-container{ margin: 0 20px 20px 25px;  }

.directory {display: inline; overflow: auto;}

.directory-image {float: left; margin-right: 17px;clear: left;}
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I dynamically resize an element's contents based on its own size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393917/can-i-dynamically-resize-an-elements-contents-based-on-its-own-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to this is `display: table`;

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
 <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
 <div class="content">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi facilisis ante id enim vestibulum viverra. Suspendisse malesuada justo et elit porttitor condimentum. Sed interdum mi dui, ut consequat risus laoreet quis. Sed quis elit nec arcu consectetur gravida vel eu lacus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras non nisl vehicula, aliquet sem nec, rutrum libero. Maecenas in mi felis. Curabitur et semper justo. Sed vel faucibus massa. Maecenas semper elementum aliquet. Nam mattis elementum fringilla. Etiam suscipit mi ut mauris vehicula, id tempor libero molestie. Vestibulum molestie nulla non adipiscing pretium. Cras volutpat magna auctor, ornare massa at, consequat lectus. Sed ac pharetra metus. Praesent eleifend nisi vitae eros fermentum fermentum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed porta vehicula augue nec elementum. Phasellus convallis lobortis dolor sed facilisis. Cras nisi elit, porta ac aliquet a, imperdiet eget turpis. Nullam euismod eros urna, in tincidunt enim feugiat id. Sed pharetra odio erat, et rhoncus massa sodales in. Nullam consectetur tortor sit amet ligula mollis, quis gravida eros pellentesque. Morbi eget laoreet mi, non euismod erat. Suspendisse elit est, dapibus a semper sed, molestie venenatis diam. Sed faucibus justo in ipsum molestie, et scelerisque ligula sodales. Vivamus sodales sodales arcu, ut bibendum diam consectetur sit amet. Donec id augue nibh. Nam vel mauris sem.
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap { display: table; width: 100%; }
.wrap img { float: left; }
.wrap .content { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
```

Then, in a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    .wrap { display: block; }
    .wrap img { float: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    .wrap .content { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. It's almost there but my image is now very small: http://www.filmcitybrighton.org/film-culture/archives/

    .item-container{display: table; width: 100%; margin: 0 20px 20px    25px;  }
    .item-container .directory-image {float: left; border:1px solid #a6a6a6; margin-right: 17px;max-width:100%; min-width:100%; height:auto;}
    .item-container .directory {
 display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; 
}

Comment: @user3198700 No need to keep `max-width: 100%` on your img. Also, add `overflow: hidden` to `.item-container` to clear the floats. Other than that, your images don't appear to be scaled down to me at all. What browser?

Comment: Oh yes - a browser thing - it looks great now on Firefox, but images are all different sizes on Chrome.

Comment: @user3198700 - as noted, remove `max-width: 100%` on the images.

Comment: Weird - I've taken off width: 100% but the images are still odd sizes on Chrome:  http://www.filmcitybrighton.org/film-culture/cinemas/

Comment: .item-container{ display: table;  overflow: hidden;}
.item-container .directory-image {float: left; height:auto;}
.item-container .directory {display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
@media screen and (max-width:480px){  .item-container { display: block; margin-right: 10px; }
.item-container .directory-image { float: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto;   height:auto;}
.item-container .directory { display: block; }}

Comment: Check your CSS, a `max-width` is still being applied (coming from elsewhere in your CSS - line 53 of integrity-light.css).

Comment: Thanks - there was a global css on IMG for max-width:100%.  I've over-ridden it on the child-theme with   min-width: 236px !important; max-width: 236px !important;   though that does restrict the images to just that size I guess... but it's a fix

Comment: It'd be nice to get an accepted answer after all this problem solving.

Comment: sorry Adam - new to this!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a float:left to the .directory div and give it a width of a certain value.

```
.directory { 
    float:left; 
    width:300px;
}
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/aMA65/

You could also add a width in percentage to .directory and .directory-image to make it more responsive. (Don't forget img { max-width:100%; height:auto; } )

Answer (score 0):

No tables or similar nonsenses needed, just pure CSS with media queries

here's how you can do it, btw re-size your browser under 400px width to see the result

you can change the value as you like for example:

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) { }
```

in this case layout change will happen when browser window width is smaller than 960px.

here's the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/SE4p5/

And if you want images to be responsive too, follow the instructions for the "img" tag form the comment above.