# How to make a responsive list with small image and text?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make this structure with this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141277/how-to-make-text-not-flow-around-image-and-to-make-it-fall-under-image-responsi) in the other way around. In that example it uses a `<div>` tag and in my case I use `<li>`. I tried to implement that source but it didn't worked. And so I have this html structure like so:

```
  <div id="body-content-right">
                <ul id="body-content-items">
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/someimage.png" alt="Some text here "/>
                        <h1>Some text here Some text here Some text here </h1>
                        <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/someimage.png" alt="Some text here "/>
                        <h1>Some text here Some text here Some text here </h1>
                        <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/someimage.png" alt="Some text here "/>
                        <h1>Some text here Some text here Some text here </h1>
                        <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/someimage.png" alt="Some text here "/>
                        <h1>Some text here Some text here Some text here </h1>
                        <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
                    </li>

                </ul>
       </div><!--end body-content-right-->
```

And I have this CSS:

```
    #body-content-right { 
        width:49.2307692308%; 
        float:right;
        margin-top:130px;
    }
    #body-content-right ul li{
        float:left; width:47.9166666667%;
        padding-bottom: 20px; 
        border:solid 1px red;
    }
    #body-content-items h1 {
        font-size: 14px; 
        color: #0067a6; 
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important; 
     }
    #body-content-items p { font-size: 13px;}

    #body-content-right ul li img{ float:left; padding-right:15px;}
```

So I have this output. (Pardon for the text)

[image]

And what I want is when the browser is being resize then the text will flow downwards but not in the scope or in the bottom part of the image. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Per se the elements you use (img, headline and p) stack over each other as block level elements. If you go mobile first your initial state already looks like the goal you want to achieve. If you create a media query now and add at a certain breakpoint the float styles you already have you should be good to go imho.

On a side note you should try to have only one h1 on your side and not for every list item: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

I would prefer articles over list items in that particular case semantically.

And if you try to build a responsive solution you should try to avoid px in general, in your example it applies to the properties margin, padding and font-size.